# android how to auto install applications on SD card

Tags: android

Is that possible for android to install all the apps on SD card once the SD card insert in the phone.

Is that possible to build something like the auto run application in flash disk on windows,
here in android the apps are all stored in sd card , i am finding a way to install them once the card insert into phone.

Comment: Wait, do you need the user to verify this? Or do you want it to just install, possibly without the user knowing?

Comment: just need to make user know there are some apps on the SD card. Just open the installation dialog is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Android wisely won't do that.

If you want you can write an application which will scan the sdcard (perhaps even automatically on insertion) for apks and use an intent to bring up the install dialog.  But the user will first have to install your application, and confirm the installation of each new app from the sdcard.  Also the device will have to be set to allow non-market sources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I heard some backup application can install apps they backed up on sd Card, i need to go further more that is once the SD insert into phone , those apps come back